# Caching the ajp connection between Apache and tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

anyone has any idea how we optimize the connection between Apache and tomcat, i am using mod ajp and therefore apache forwarding the request to tomcat, but my tomcat apps contains many images which take more bandwidth, how we can optimize this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear, but my humble guess is that you could use [Apache's mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_cache.html) to cache the Tomcat stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number of threads allocated by Tomcat using the `maxThreads` attribute in server.xml. You should also read about the `MaxClients` setting in Apache, it usually needs to be set in conjunction with Tomcat's `maxThreads`.

Another way to make things faster would be to drop Apache and serve everything directly from Tomcat. Of course this is only possible if you don't need Apache for anything else, like PHP, URL rewriting, proxying, etc.

For a good book about Tomcat configuration, I suggest *Tomcat: The Definitive Guide*, by *J. Brittain, I. Darwin*. It's a few years old and mainly about Tomcat 6, but I believe most of it is still true for Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

Either use mod_cache as suggested by @Janne Pikkarainen, or move the images directly into the Apache HTTPD htdocs tree and avoid proxying requests for them to Tomcat at all. Cuts down the size of your web-app too ;-)